# Which cybersecurity job is most likely to be remote

Tags: career

When looking to get into cybersecurity what job/certification is most likely to be available as a remote position?

Comment: Probably a bit too broad - selling cybersecurity services might be entirely remote based, but probably isn't what you're after. Also, specific types of testing may have different requirements depending on the client - government work might require on-site presence, whereas a very similar test for a small business might be performed from home.

Comment: "Most likely"? That's an odd constraint. All can be. Managed services are becoming the norm. I could say that a cybersecurity reporter is most likely to be remote. As is being an author, or a penetration tester for hire. I think you will need to explain or narrow your scope.

Comment: Now that it's 2020 and a pandemic has hit, forcing everyone to reevaluate their WFH policies, it's possible that any job could be remote.

Answer (score 1):

I see a few vCISO roles now and then that are virtual, they would be at the top of the career path. Further down the path you could find pen testing work that is purely virtual, as well as log analyst roles. Truly, you could make most infosec work virtual with the exception of forensics, in-person social engineering, and some incident response. I think the key will be using the right search terms, and using them correctly. Look for "virtual" as a location (to keep from returning "virtual machines" or such from polluting your results. Similarly, "remote" is only good as a location. Listings with many locations listed are more likely to be remote jobs.

PM me for a few good recruiters if you are interested in going that route.